# Siamese Twin Planets?

Tags: internal-consistency, planets, physics, earth-like

### Premise

I want to explore the possibility of a planet that is extremely misshapen. If we were to extrapolate what we have observed from our solar system and the extra-solar planets discovered so far, we would have to be conservative about such a possibility because nothing of the sort has been discovered. Moreover, our understanding of physics tells us, all else equal, the more massive something is the more spherical it becomes (not a perfect sphere typically). This phenomenon is easily seen in asteroids since they are less massive than planets, they can take on a Siamese twin shape:

[image]

*Itokawa Asteroid, discovered 1998 by [LINEAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lincoln_Near-Earth_Asteroid_Research)*

Now if we were considering very small dwarf planets, this would be a piece of cake, because like asteroids, the mass can be small for misshapen bodies. However, I'm interested in Siamese twins that are [earth-like](/questions/tagged/earth-like). So with all of the aforementioned odds stacked against this idea, I still wonder if somewhere in the vast, vast universe there might be a freak accident of astronomical proportions that could allow for a planet to have a Siamese twin. A few ways I thought of to approach are below. The bold face denotes the part of the idea that I feel needs the most of a [reality-check](/questions/tagged/reality-check):

- the Siamese twin planets appears big, **but have hollow cores**,
  allowing for its mass to be small enough for the planets to be
  misshapen.
- the Siamese twin planet shape is maintained via equilibrium of forces. **Something is pulling the planets apart** at just the right amount against gravity for the Siamese twin shape to exist. Maybe a rogue, black-hole at just the right distance?
  [image]

**Question:**
Can any of my ideas for my Earth mass Siamese twin planets to take form be plausible? If you so desire, feel free to hypothesize your own set of "perfect storm" circumstances.

**Success Metric:** Create Earth mass Siamese twin bodies (can't really call them planets any more, because they are not round) that remain so for at least 100 million years (in other words, it doesn't have to be permanent). If the solution is statistically remote, that's ok. The key is just not violating any known laws of physics.
**Further Clarifications:**

- Mass: both twins have near Earth mass
- Fusion Onset: can be at formation or later on
- Area of Fusion: equatorial region of planets
- Fusion Degree: configurable. Could be a slight join or a deep join. Quick reference in the diagram below:

[image]

- Other: Other things like Planet composition, nearby objects are entirely configurable

Comment: The definition of a planet involves a body that has been rounded by its own gravity. If it is not round, it is not a planet.

Comment: You might want to consider [downsizing the images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25051/resizing-an-image-in-a-post/25052#25052) by adding an "m" before the file extension ("blahblah _m_ .jpg"), minus the quotation marks and spaces.

Comment: Think of an earth size planet as being a big bag of molten iron with a skin the thickness of an orange peel.  Slap two of them together, and they will immediately blob together into a bigger blob or molten iron and the skin will reform as it cools. The "blobbing" process will happen in hours, although it may take years for the shock waves to settle out.

Comment: You do understand that the mischievous black hold will attract *both* planet A *and* planet B?

Comment: @AlexP I was hoping that physics would allow for a black hole of a certain size and of just the right distance to attract only Twin A. But perhaps you are right. Maybe we could assume a small black hole opposite Twin B as well? That way the pulls are symmetric in that the Siamese twins are pulled by each black hole gently enough not to destroy be destroyed but hard enough to counteract the gravity pulling them towards each other. So, would two smallish black holes be more plausible?

Comment: What keeps the two smallish black holes above the planets? Gravity works both ways, see Newton's third law: any action has an equal and opposite reaction. The black hole attracts the planet means the planet attracts the black hole with the same force.

Comment: related: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4460/could-two-planets-be-tidally-locked-to-each-other-so-close-they-share-their-atmo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What would happen to the Moon if it was lowered onto the Earth?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/118198/what-would-happen-to-the-moon-if-it-was-lowered-onto-the-earth)

Comment: @Jasper, check out the dates on this post and the one you linked as a duplicate.  If anything that post (15 Jul 18) is a duplicate of this one (29 Jun 18).  If you're sure they're duplicates, you might want to retract the vote here and submit it over there.  (Note that I'm not convinced they're duplicates as that other appears to involve impact and this one does not.)

Comment: @JBH -- I did check the dates, but I misread them as both being in July 2018.  Oddly, there are situations where an older question has been "validly" closed as a duplicate of a newer question.

Comment: It is sometimes called a [rocheworld](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/worldbuilding.php#rocheworld), and is actually physically possible - Roche lobes allows you to cheat the Roche limit. The author of the quoted novel was a physicist, and did the calculations. Here is [another example](http://panoptesv.com/RPGs/Settings/VergeWorlds/Worlds/Valleya.php) made by another physicist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Not likely. What you are looking for is called a contact binary. But you could have non-contact binaries.

Once they enter the ***slight join*** phase, any speed or other force keeping them apart will be outperformed by their mutual attraction. The effect of your rogue black hole can't be stable, and the relative speeds of the planets will slow down as they fuse.

---

A planet with enough mass will necessarily become rounded by its gravity in the short term (astronomically speaking). This is called [hydrostatic equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatic_equilibrium).

The gravitational influence of other bodies, or its own spin can make it more eccentric (a spheroid rather than a perfect sphere), but it will still be pretty round.

How much mass gets an astronomical body to hydrostatic equilibrium (HE)? It will depend on the planet's composition, but having a liquid interior helps a lot. Anyway, the answer is far less than Earth's.

As a reference, Saturn's moon [Iapetus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iapetus_(moon)) is the biggest object in the solar system known not to be in HE, but still round-ish:

[image]
<sup>*Iapetus as seen by Cassini. Taken from Wikipedia*</sup>

Its mass is 1/5000th that of Earth. About anything above that would become rounded.

Although a mass limit above which *everything* becomes in HE is difficult to obtain, it helps having a few ideas in consideration:

- [Ceres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceres_(dwarf_planet)), with half of Iapetus's mass, is in HE
- [Mimas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimas_(moon)), with a 25th of Ceres's mass, has a HE shape
- The result of the collision of two planets will necessarily generate enough heat to partly liquefy them, making the subsequent HE easier.

---

As for **non-contact binary planets**, [they are possible](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=binary%20planets%20is%3Aquestion). Bear in mind the closer they get, the more likely they are to be tidally locked.

If they get close enough, tides will slow them down and make them less able to keep distance. Once they get even closer, they'll become a [contact binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_binary_(small_Solar_System_body)), but it will be short lived in astronomical scale. their atmospheres will cause friction and they'll quickly decay into a (catastrophic) collision.

---

There is a number of [contact binary stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_binary), almost touching, but separated by their own pressure. After several million years they start sharing a *[common envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_envelope)* (atmosphere-analog), but they are theorized to either expel part of their envelope, losing contact, or merge within a time frame of years (not millions, sorry).

Contact binary stars seem to be less frequent as the mass of the involved stars decrease, because [they become less stable](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2041-8205/798/2/L42/meta).

Comment: That's HUGE! You might want to consider [downsizing the images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25051/resizing-an-image-in-a-post/25052#25052) by adding an "m" or even an "s" before the file extension ("blahblah _m_ .jpg"), minus the quotation marks and spaces.

Comment: @FoxElemental, thank you. Didn't know that

Answer (score 10):

> Can any of my ideas for my Earth mass Siamese twin planets to take form be plausible?

No, not for an Earth mass body

> the Siamese twin planets appears big, but have hollow cores

This configuration is highly unstable: the more dense material will sink toward the center of mass. So the hollow center would not last, especially after an impact which will necessarily melt part if not all of the planets

> Something is pulling the planets apart at just the right amount against gravity

you start from a sphere. you can either get an ellipsoid because of rotation, or a bulged shape by constant pull from one direction.

> Can any of my ideas for my Earth mass Siamese twin planets to take form be plausible?

No

Comment: I think the external pull hypothesis could be explored further. Suppose we had two Siamese twin, Earth mass ellipsoids? Maybe they are not *planets* in the conventional sense of the word, but if they have Earth mass and are co-joined, that's all we need for success on my question. (I stopped using "planet" to avoid confusion)

Comment: @ArashHowaida, above a certain mass you cannot escape the spherical form...

Comment: Yes, I conceded that in my question. The point is rather, if Twin A is about to collide into Twin B but a rogue black hole (or something else) pulls on Twin A at just the right position and intensity that it facilitates the Siamese twin shape. I don't think this contradicts the link between mass and spherical form. It's just a lucky circumstance that results in the Siamese twin shape, no?

Comment: @ArashHowaida, then it will two partially molten masses, which will reach equilibrium again (spherical shape)

Comment: I'm not sure what the timeframe is on your equilibrium, but the success metric only needs 100 million years in Siamese twin shape. Suppose another freak accident occurred that chilled the planets down at the same time the black hole pulled Twin A?

Comment: @ArashHowaida There are very few freak accidents that "chill" planets (it's way easier to add heat than remove it).  Moreover, the tidal stresses caused by the proximity of the black hole and the other mass would be more than sufficient to keep both masses molten until equilibrium was reached.

Answer (score 1):

The idea has been explored in fiction. I wonder if you may be interested in examples?

Hal Clement wrote a classic of physics-based science fiction about a massive planet, fast-spinning hence very oblate and with many times greater weight felt at poles than equator:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesklin

In 'TV Century 21' children's weekly, one story of comic strip 'Zero-X' featured a 'first known Siamese Twin planet'- two linked doughnut-shapes! (I recall seeing it then but haven't traced it further. The first issue was published on 23 January 1965; with issue #105 (21 January 1967) Zero-X was added, by Angus Allan and Mike Noble, continuing into 1968.)

Various works have featured a hollow Earth (notably Edgar Rice Burroughs' inner realm Pellucidar, with a central sun of its own and an internal moon)
or other hollow worlds - for example, among Neil R. Jones' many Zoromes stories is 'The Sunless World' (Amazing Stories, December 1934).

Happy reading!

Answer (score 0):

### Yes. It is called a Rocheworld, or Contact Binary

The earliest fictional [example](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/worldbuilding.php#rocheworld) I know of is from physicist and hard-SF novelist Dr Robert L. Forward, who uses the term Rocheworld. The term Contact Binary also exists, though it is more commonly used for stars.

Here is [another example](http://panoptesv.com/RPGs/Settings/VergeWorlds/Worlds/Valleya.php) made by another physicist, Dr Luke Campbell. Side-note: [Vergeworlds](http://panoptesv.com/RPGs/Settings/VergeWorlds/TheVerge.php) is a quite fascinating hard-SF setting, and I recommend looking at it for both its tech, Fermi-compatible aliens, and Relativity-compatible FTL method (two words: "causality attack").

The reason it works despite being in each-other's Roche limits is because [Roche Lobes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_lobe) and, at those scales, the fluid nature of the bodies mess things up.

There are two interesting consequences to keep in mind, on such a world. Despite the variable gravity, it is always normal to the surface: the ground is always horizontal, even in the weird region where the two lobes are touching. And the atmosphere has the same pressure everywhere: if the minimal surface gravity zone is too weak to keep atmosphere, there won't be any atmosphere on the entire surface.