# How can Nebulae be harvested?

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, space-colonization

My question is about a far off and seclusive colony in the reaches of the [Orion nebula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_Nebula). As they are relatively isolated they have resorted to harvesting the nebula itself for resources.

What I want to know is how this can accomplished and what would be needed to facilitate it?

**This can include futuristic technology as long as it is conceivably possible.**

Comment: They'd need a very big vacuum cleaner ;)

Comment: That contains starforming regions.  Are you saying they are not near any stars or star-in-formation?

Comment: The way you harvest a nebula is to wait until it forms nice bite sized chunks I like to call "stars", or "planets". The most practical thing to harvest in a nebula, would have to be a brown dwarf.

Comment: What do you want to harvest? There isn't anything obvious worth harvesting there, but maybe you had something in mind that actually makes sense? Maybe for your story, you could invent some kind of bs radiation that has to be harvested in a nebula. Everyone is doing those kind of things, there is nothing wrong about it

Comment: Relevant: [What are the effects of a planet staying long-term inside of a nebula?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/14499/29)

Comment: something like this https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/47982/20315

Answer (score 6):

It's **incredibly** impractical to attempt to harvest a nebula.

[Density of a Nebula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_nebula#Physical_characteristics) is somewhere between 100 and 10,000 particles per cubic centimeter. Really, really young nebula can have about 1,000,000 particles per cubic centimeter.

For comparison, sea level atmosphere has about 25,000,000,000,000,000,000 particles per cubic centimeter. The [theoretical maximum vacuum you can create](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_chamber) at sea level is aproxamately 0.0008534% of an atmosphere - Or a density of roughly 213,350,000,000,000 particles per cubic centimeter.

To put it simply, the theoretical "Best" vacuum you can achieve on Earth is about 213 million times more dense than the densest of nebula.

*Fun Fact*: The [atmosphere on the Lunar Surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_the_Moon) is between 80,000 atoms per cubic centimeter and 1,000,000 atoms per cubic centimeter, depending on which part of that article you look at. That's roughly about the same density as a nebula.

Now, let's do some more math.

[Helium](https://www.livescience.com/28552-facts-about-helium.html) has a density of 0.0001785 grams per cubic centimeter. Not a lot. It has an Atomic Mass of 4.002602. This means one [Mole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_(unit)) of Helium is a tad over 4 grams. Using this, we can get that one cubic centimeter of Helium at one atmosphere is around the ballpark of 26,856,000,000,000,000,000 individual particles, or atoms, of Helium.

In the thickest nebula, you would have to collect 26,856,000,000,000 cubic centimeters. That's just shy of 27 cubic kilometers of "space" to get one cubic centimeter of Helium.

(A note: I was thinking of Helium-3 when writing this, as it's used in a lot of sci-fi space reactors. But it turns out Helium-3 has an atomic mass of [3.0160293](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium-3) and not 4.002602. I'll probably go back and re-do the math in the morning, unless someone answers better than I.

Also, it's fairly late for me so my math exacts may not be 100% correct. The general idea should be fairly correct even if the numbers aren't.)

For nearly anything I can think of, the energy you would get from harvesting that material would not equal the energy expenditure that you would have to make to harvest it.

Comment: I don't see why this couldn't be done through the use of something like a [Bussard Ramjet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bussard_ramjet). As long as the nebula was between some important planets then the traffic inbetween those planets could be used to harvest some of the nebula.

Comment: @user3201708 *"I don't see why this couldn't be done through the use of something like a Bussard Ramjet."* [Newton's third law of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_laws_of_motion#Newton.27s_third_law) might give you some trouble.

Comment: Nah, a cryopump can go down to $10^5$ molecules per cm$^3$

Answer (score 2):

The known process which compacts a nebula makes use of gravity to condense it into stars.

A futuristic technology, imitating gravity effects, can force the nebula matter to the collection point like a galactic vacuum cleaner, where the molecules are then further processed for the colony use.

The momentum of the harvested mass can be used to generate energy for the colony, which of course need energy to survive.